# css image with border-radius

Tags: html, css, image, sass

I am trying to replicate this style, which has a background image, on the other hand I have a div over it that has a right border-radius, I can't do it, I provided the following options adapting them, but I couldn't

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R06XU.png)

[Transparent hollow or cut out circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286550/transparent-hollow-or-cut-out-circle)

```
div{
    position:relative;
    width:500px; height:200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
div:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left:175px; top:25px;
    border-radius:100%;
    width:150px; height:150px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2000px #E3DFD2;
}

body{background: url('https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8760/17195790401_ceeeafcddb_o.jpg';
```

---

[Background with radius-top inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27294802/background-with-radius-top-inside)

```
div {
    background:lightgreen;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    padding:100px 0 0 0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
div:before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    background:white;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    border-radius:40%;
    transform:translatey(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The cut out example with the circle suits fine, You just need to play around with the values in the DevTools/Inspector.
Adjust heights/widths of the `:before` to stretch the curve to your liking or even mess with % of border radius, then the border width for how much space around it, the `top` and `left` to position it to the edges, then use the parent container to trim off right and bottom areas.

```css
.banner {
  background: url(https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8760/17195790401_ceeeafcddb_o.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.shape {
  position: relative;
  width: 170px;
  height: 440px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.shape:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
  top: -200px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 151px;
  height: 440px;
  border: 200px solid #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="shape">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can do this by `clip-path` property ..**

**Note :** minimum width required otherwise shape will not display

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
display: flex;
}
.left{
  width: 10%;
}

.image {
  width: 90%;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url(https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8760/17195790401_ceeeafcddb_o.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  clip-path: circle(100% at 100% 50%);

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
  </div>
</div>
```